# Change GridView Item BackGround when is Unchecked

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a `CustomAdapter` that works fine.
The `Adapter` insert data into my `Android GridView`.
Now i want when an item is checked the `BackGround` of the `Item` change to white, and when the other Item is selected, the previous selected Item color chage to `GridView` background, i mean just with `SingleChoiceMode`.
I have wrote this :

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(gridView.isItemChecked(position)) {
                view = gridView.getChildAt(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else {
                view = gridView.getChildAt(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(124333); //the color code is the background color of GridView
            }
        }
    });
```

But just the first `If` works, it means when i select a row, the color change to white, but when i select the other row, the previous is still white and the new selected is white too.
What should i write in `else statement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` every time you pressed on any item of your `GridView` for refresh `GridView`

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // call it here
            if(gridView.isItemChecked(position)) {
                view = gridView.getChildAt(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else {
                view = gridView.getChildAt(position);
                view.setBackgroundColor(124333); //the color code is the background color of GridView
            }
        }
```

If you just want to change the color of selected item in `GridView`, you can use `android:listSelector` for your `GridView` xml

```
<GridView
    ...
    android:listSelector="#ff0000" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: Thx alot Dude.
I used the XML one.